# outline is not visible for an anchor tag in IE browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

here I have some html in which i have `<a href=""></a>` 
which suppose to show outline while getting focus but it is not working

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<div class="allItems"> 
<a tabindex="0" href="#" target="_blank" class="popup outlne">
    <img data-pubimgid="13" src="xyz.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
this is my html structure
```

i tried to set it up with css as like

```
a:focus {
    outline: auto !important;
    outline-color: red !important;
}
```

but it is also not working for above HTML structure in IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
 a:focus{
  outline: 1px dotted red !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

add this Meta tag in your site

Comment: I have it but it has IE=10
see <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">